# Wicket and responding with "not HTML" to requests

Tags: servlets, wicket

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere else - but I don't know where

I need to respond to HTTP requests from a partner, in our wicket website. The partner expected the response body to say "OK" or anything else in the case of an error

Is there a "nice" way to do this? ... or am I going to be stuck adding a servlet to my (previously) pretty Wicket application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use resources for that:

```
class OkResource implements IResource {
    @Override
    public void respond(Attributes attributes) {
        WebResponse resp = (WebResponse) attributes.getResponse();
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.write("OK");
    }
}
```

And register it in your Application class

```
@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    getSharedResources().add("confirm", new OkResource());
    mountResource("confirm", new SharedResourceReference("confirm"));
}
```

so that it can be accessed through something like `http://host/app/confirm`.

Just observe that here you registering a single instance of the resource, so it must be thread-safe, since multiple requests can call it simultaneously.

**[EDIT]**
In Wicket 1.4:

```
class OkResource extends Resource {
    @Override
    public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
        return new StringResourceStream("ok", "text/plain");
    }
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    getSharedResources().add("confirm", new OkResource());
    mountSharedResource("confirm", "confirm");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

... what's IResource's equivalent in Wicket 1.4?

Comment: `Resource`. Also, instead of just responding to the output directly, you have to return an `IResourceStream` implementation that does that.